# Finding least difference between max and min value of all possible sets of numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

There are *n* arrays of *k* size each.

```
a0[0],a0[1],......a0[k-1]
a1[0],a1[1],......a1[k-1]
.
.
.
an-1[0],an-1[1], .... an-1[k-1]
```

There are no duplicates at all and all the arrays are sorted.

Now a Set of size *n* is constructed by taking any value randomly from each of the arrays.
e.g one such set can be `{a0[0],a1[3],a2[2],.... an-1[k-1]}`.

My goal is to find out the min and max elements in all possible Sets such that the difference between the min and max is the lowest.

Example (k=3,n=3)

```
[3 7 11]
[1 12 15]
[4 19 21]
```

So mathematically there will be 27 such sets

```
(3 1 4) (3 12 4) (3 15 4)
(3 1 19) (3 12 19) (3 15 19)
(3 1 21) (3 12 21) (3 15 21)

(7 1 4) (7 12 4) (7 15 4)
(7 1 19) (7 12 19) (7 15 19)
(7 1 21) (7 12 21) (7 15 21)

(11 1 4) (7 12 4) (11 15 4)
(11 1 19) (7 12 19) (11 15 19)
(11 1 21) (7 12 21) (11 15 21)
```

After computing min and max values of all these sets we can conclude that (3 1 4) is the set for which difference between min (1) and max (4) is the global minimum or lowest.

So we will output 3 as the global minimum difference and the corresponding pair which is (3 4). If there are multiple global minima then print them all. Please suggest the algorithm with better time and space complexity. We can't go for brute force approach.

Comment: EDIT: dont do drugs kids. leaving my old comment here because it's so incredibly stupid: "I am incredibly dense at this time of day so i could be wrong - but if there are no repeats, just find the min diff. This is done in O(n*k) time due to pre sorted. Now find all pairs that have this diff. (+O(n*k) due to sorting) Then all sets that consist of a number between each pair (+ pairsFound*O(n*k)). = O(n*k)?"

Comment: If i understand the question correctly , if I join N array of K size into One Array and then Sort them , After that i pick the first P numbes ( Set = P size) , i can get the min of Pn-p0 ?

Comment: How large do you expect `n` to be?

Comment: @simplecoder: That won't work because the Sets must have one number from each array.

Comment: @Jim , you are right . i missed that in question . So can we do Set of N elements = {Min of Each Array}

Comment: You can do it in O(nklogn) using heaps. See below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Minimum difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401915/the-minimum-difference)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the set in which the largest difference within its elements is globally minimal. (I will call that the range of the set)

Start with k sets, with each of them initially contain the an element from the first array. For each set, the minimum and maximum would be equal to the element itself.
For your example that would be {3}, {7} and {11}.

Then you move on to the second array. For each set, you have to pick an element from that array that minimizes the new range. Ideally you would select an element that does not increase the range (but that's not possible now). If that's not possible, select the elements that expand your sets going both direction (plus and minus). For the example that would give you {1-3}, {3-12},{1-7},{7-12},{1-11} and {11-12}. From these *2k* sets, you can remove sets that are overlapping. For example, the set {1-7} will always have a larger or equal range compared to the set {1-3}. You don't need to investigate the {1-7} set. You end up with sets {1-3} and {11-12}.

Moving on to the third array, again select the elements that expand the ranges of each sets as small as possible. You end up with {1-4}, {11-19} and {4-12}. Then just select the one with the lowest range.

Comment: Can we prove an upper bound on the number of generated sets?

Comment: What I got so far: Suppose you have x sets in the i'th array. For the new array you have k new points that can act as the new minimum or maximum of a set. A set will not grow if any of the k points falls in the set. If a set (A) does grow, it picks one of the new points to be it's new end point. If another set (B) picks the same new point as the same end point, it will overlap with A and A or B can be removed. This limits the growth per array by 2*k extra sets. This gives a bound 2*n*k but it does not take all overlap into account

Answer (score 2):

Complexity of this algorithm is O(n*k*logn)

Select only the first element from each row and create a min heap and a max heap.

Calculate the current difference (=head(maxHeap)-head(minheap))

Remove the head of minHeap (and the corresponding element from maxHeap) and add the next element from the corresponding array (corresponding to removed element) to both minHeap and maxHeap.

Repeat it until all the elements in at one of the array are exhausted.

Complexity: You add/remove nk elements and update takes O(n) time at most. So complexity is O(nklogn).

Note: It is not exactly your stock heap. The minHeap contains pointer to the same element in maxHeap and vice versa. When you delete an element from minHeap, you can find the link to the maxHeap and delete it too. Also whenever position of a particular element changes, appropriate changes are made to the link in the other heap.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that the min and max are from different rows, which is one of the OP's requirements. It also won't find duplicates, which was another of the OP's requirements.

Comment: @JimMischel Of cource it does. At any moment there is exactly one element from each row in minHeap and maxHeap (and it is the same element).

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all `n * k` elements.

Say our current element has value `v`. Let's calculate the minimum difference assuming that `v` is the minimum value in the resulting  n-tuple.

Binary search the position of `v` in the other `n - 1` arrays (since they're sorted, we can do it), and notice that to reduce the difference it's optimal to pick the smallest elements that are greater than or equal than `v` for all the other arrays. This is precisely what the binary search gives us.

**An example:**

```
[3 7 11]
[1 12 15]
[4 19 21]
```

If we take `v = 1` on the second array, then we'll pick 3 on the first array, and 4 on the second.

The complexity is `O(N * K * N * log(N)) = O(N^2 * log(N) * K)`.

Comment: i like your algorithm more, +1. can you explain where I went wrong in my comment above? Thanks! EDIT: oh nvm it's just wrong yay coffee

Comment: How can we find the minimum difference in O(n*k)?

Comment: I had assumed that as each array is sorted, we could in linear time locate the min difference in each array - rolling counter, no?

Comment: I then failed to take into account the obvious case of overlapping values in the arrays :/

Comment: Maybe it's a silly question, but what is the "minimum difference in each array" (difference of consecutive elements)?

Comment: yep, exactly what i had in mind (and no silly questions when analyzing silly proposals hahaha)

Comment: You might be able to improve this in the average case by maintaining state. After you generate `[7,12,19]`, you change the first item to `11`, and only binary search those arrays whose corresponding value is smaller than `11`. The worst case remains the same, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the result Set as a simple 1xn array

```
[3]
[1]
[4]
```

where the global difference is 3 (maximum of 4 less minimum of 1).

Now consider an expanded definition of Set, call it MultiSet. A MultiSet is an array where each element contains an ordered set of items.

```
[3 7 11]
[1 12 15]
[4 19 21]
```

We can calculate the global difference (call it 'cost') by the difference between the maximum 'last' value of each row and the minimum 'first' value of each row. In this case the cost will be the difference between 21 (`max(11,15,21)`) and 1 (`min(3,1,4)`), which is 20.

The process will now be to iterate the MultiSet until we reach minimum cost using the following algorithm:

- identify the row with the lowest value. If this row has only one element then continue, otherwise consider the potential cost reduction of removing the values from this row which are lower than the lowest value from any other row.
- identify the row with the highest value. If this row has only element then continue, otherwise consider the potential cost reduction of removing the values from this row which are higher than the highest value from any other row.
- remove those values identified above and continue to the next highest/lowest items.
  -
- If lowest and highest values are both in single-item rows then the cost has been minimised.

To demonstrates in the given example, the original cost of 20 can be reduced to 18 by removing the lowest value of `1` (the lowest value in the MultiSet which is lower than any other rows minimum), or reduced to 14 by removing the highest values of `19` and `21` (the highest values in the MultiSet which are higher than any other row's maximum, i.e. `15`) from the final row. The resulting MultiSet would be

```
[3 7 11]
[1 12 15]
[4]
```

The second iteration has us remove the `12` and `15` to reduce the cost to 10.

```
[3 7 11]
[1]
[4]
```

And the third and final iteration has us remove the `7` and `11` to reduce the cost to 3. After the third iteration the global difference can no longer be minimised, thus the solution is reached.

The complexity? Upper bounded by O(n * m * log(n) * k)

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
private static ElementData calcMin(int[] n1Arr, int[] n2Arr, int[] n3Arr) {

    ElementData data = new ElementData();// added just to know which two elements algo has picked

    int[] mixArr = { n1Arr[0], n2Arr[0], n3Arr[0] };
    Arrays.sort(mixArr);
    int minValue = mixArr[2] - mixArr[0];

    data.setMinValue(minValue);
    data.setHighValue(mixArr[2]);
    data.setLowValue(mixArr[0]);

    int tempValue = 0;
    for (int n1 : n1Arr) {

        for (int n2 : n2Arr) {

            for (int n3 : n3Arr) {

                int[] mixArr1 = { n1, n2, n3 };
                Arrays.sort(mixArr1);

                tempValue = mixArr1[2] - mixArr1[0];
                if (minValue > tempValue) {
                    minValue = tempValue;

                    data = new ElementData();
                    data.setMinValue(minValue);
                    data.setHighValue(mixArr1[2]);
                    data.setLowValue(mixArr1[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```