# minimum difference between numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting, minimum

We have K different sets of numbers. We have to choose a number from each set, so that the difference between the higher and the lower number is the *minimum*.

Any ideas?

Comment: How many elements are in each set? And how big can K be?

Comment: if you choose minimum from each set - will that work ?

Comment: @simplecoder: Clearly not; simply consider the two sets {1,2,3} and {-3,-2,-1}

Comment: 0<K<1000 , elements in each set <1000

Comment: we search the minimum difference, which means that in Pieter's case our output is 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12401915/484293

Comment: Please show some effort of your own. For example, start by telling us what approaches you considered and why they didn't work. That way we can help you and you will actually be able to learn something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12401915/469210 is the same problem with sorting lists rather than sets.  You can transform your problem, and hence use that solution, by sorting the contents of your sets to form the sorted lists.

Comment: @Pieter if K>0 then it should work right ? thoughts

Comment: @simplecoder K is the __number of sets__ not the lesser bound of the sets. There is no assumption made on the numbers found in the sets. And clearly, taking the minimum of each set is _NEVER_ a reliable method, even when there are bounds to the numbers. (Another simple example : the sets {0,1,2,3} and {2,3,4} -> the answer is 0 by taking "2" from the two sets)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding least difference between max and min value of all possible sets of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909944/finding-least-difference-between-max-and-min-value-of-all-possible-sets-of-numbe)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (written in Haskell)?

```
import Data.List (minimum, maximum, minimumBy)

minDiff (x:xs) = comb (head x) (diff $ matches (head x)) x where
  lenxs = length xs
  diff m = maximum m - minimum m
  matches y = minimumBy (\a b -> compare (diff a) (diff b)) $ p [] 0 where
    md = map (minimumBy (\a b -> compare (abs (a - y)) (abs (b - y)))) xs
    mds = [m | m <- foldl (\b a -> filter (\z -> abs (z - y) == abs (y - md!!a)) (xs!!a) : b) [] [0..lenxs - 1]]
    p result index
      | index == lenxs = [y:result]
      | otherwise      = do
          p' <- mds!!index
          p (p':result) (index + 1)
  comb result difference []     = matches result
  comb result difference (z:zs) =
    let diff' = diff (matches z)
    in if diff' < difference
          then comb z diff' zs
          else comb result difference zs


OUTPUT:
*Main> minDiff [[1,3,5,9,10],[2,4,6,8],[7,11,12,13]]
[5,6,7]
```

Comment: Probably unreadable to anyone who doesn't know Haskell (or at least difficult to read). Try to include an algorithm description, comments and/or pseudo-code when giving algorithm answers.