# Find minimum difference between Max and min element of row made from one element from each column in column wise sorted Matrix

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I came across a problem but not able to get a better approach than O(m X n)

A 2D array contains column wise sorted array, Is there any way to choose one element from each column and create a row such that the difference of maximum and minimum element in that row should be minimum. for example

```
A = 1  2  5
    3  4  15
    7 11  17
```

The answer should be 2 as u can choose 3 from first col, 4 from second and 5 from third making row 3 4 5 making max - min 2.

Is there a way to get this in O(Row * Col)

Ps: Its not from any ongoing competition.

Comment: You have to inspect every element, so ...

Comment: `You have to inspect every element` (Oliver Charlesworth) - well, if there was one column starting with a value that sorts after the last value of all other columns and another with a last value to come before the first values of every other, you would be done with 2(n-1) comparisons. (Not seeing how this might lead to a _fast_ approach. "Someone" should establish/argue a _worst case_.)

Comment: Are the values unique in each row/column/in the whole matrix?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: `I have updated the question` sadly, so much that it invalidates previous answers, if not up-votes and _favourites_. I'd much prefer the modified question posted on its own and this one kept as it used to be, with additional specification about the permissibility of duplicate values.

Comment: Sorry @greybeard ! Correct It will be 2.

Comment: (The question as modified in revisions 2 & 3 is pretty much a standard one. Take the first row as a starting point and establish its range. A lower range may be possible by leaving out the minimum value, so: feed a min heap with one value from each column keeping track of _max_ and lowest range so far. At each step, replace _min_ in heap with the next value from same column - without such a value, you're done.)

Comment: @greybeard yeah ! I got your logic :) Thanks

Comment: (Morphed into a duplicate of, e.g, [The Minimum difference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12401915/3789665). None of the linked questions got a remarkably enlightening answer, and none has a score over 2, let alone the 5 you got for your question in its original form)

Answer (score 1):

The runtime of `O(m*n)` is in fact linear, as there are `m*n` elements in the input. Within a sublinear runtime bound, it is impossible to read every element, which means that without additional assumptions the described algorithm is optimal with respect to runtime complexity.

Comment: Yes you are correct that it's linear approach O(n*m) but is there any way to get it better than this using the fact that columns are sorted.

If I get a better solution i will post here. :)

Answer (score 1):

(Too lazy to use *difference between the maximum and minimum entry in a row*, I'll call that *range*.)
There are a lot of special cases one could take advantage of, one of which kills the apparent trivial worst case of one and the same value for each and every entry, where every row has a range of 0: when a range of 0 is found, searching for a lower one is excessive.
I suggest as a worst case a matrix filled row first with successive values "and extra space around the last one" - starting one column further down every row

```
 1  2  3  5
11  7  8  9
15 17 13 14
```

, where the range is the same for every row, a lower range *might* exist (even with duplicates forbidden) and I don't see how to avoid inspecting each and every entry. For one, my favourite "trick" doesn't work:
For a newly found minimum range candidate, look at the next values in the columns containing the minimum and maximum entries, respectively: while the difference doesn't drop below the candidate, the range can't and rows can be skipped. (Another chance for identical values in a row to mess things up - please specify in the question whether they are permitted.)
Then, there are columns starting with a value that sorts after the last value of all other columns: these contribute row maxima (assuming ascending order). Likewise, columns with a last value to come before the first values of every other contribute row minima. (For unique values, weaker conditions suffice.)